# How to calculate $\int_{x^2+y^2=R^2\\ 0\leq z\leq R}(x^2+z^2)dS$?

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

I use $\begin{cases}
x=R\cos \theta\\
y=R\sin \theta\\
z=z
\end{cases}$
, then $dS=Rd\theta dz$,
and I find
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^RR(R^2\cos^2\theta+z^2)d\theta dz=\frac{5\pi R^4}{3}.$$

But my classmate got $\frac{4\pi R^4}{3},$ which is right? Can anyone help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The correct result is yours:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\int_0^RR(R^2\cos^2\theta+z^2)dz\right)d\theta =
\int_{0}^{2\pi}(R^4\cos^2\theta+\frac{R^4}{3})d\theta=\pi R^4+\frac{2\pi R^4}{3}=\frac{5\pi R^4}{3}.$$